# large image onclick becomes another image?

Tags: javascript

I need to make it so that the big images become the one that comes after (1,2,3). However, I need 3 to become 1 and if a 4th image was added, the code would still work. I also need to make it so that when the document opens, the first image is displayed in large with the thumbnail appearing darker than the two others.

Here is my code right now

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>problème 1 </title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="thumbs">
    <img src="thumbs/img1.jpg" id="img1" width="150" height="102">

    <img src="thumbs/img2.jpg" id="img2" width="150" height="108">

    <img src="thumbs/img3.jpg" id="img3" width="150" height="100">
</div>
<div>
    <img id="displayLarge" width="1200" height="800">

</div>
<script>
    "use strict"
    var thumbs_ref = document.getElementById("thumbs");
    var imgs = thumbs_ref.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++){
        imgs[i].onmouseover = augmenteOpacite;
        imgs[i].onmouseout = diminueOpacite;
        imgs[i].onclick = showLarge;
        imgs[i].style.opacity = 0.6;
    }

    function diminueOpacite(e){
        var evt = e || window.event;
        var cible = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
        cible.style.opacity = 0.6;
    }

    function augmenteOpacite(e){
        var evt = e || window.event;
        var cible = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
        cible.style.opacity = 1;
    }
    function showLarge(e){
        var evt = e || window.event;
        var cible = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
        console.log(cible.src);
        var filePath = cible.src;
        var lastSep = filePath.lastIndexOf("/");
        if (lastSep == -1) {
            lastSep = filePath.lastIndexOf("\\"); // windows
        }
        if (lastSep != -1){
            var fichierNom = filePath.substr(lastSep+1);
        }
        else {
            fichierNom = cible.str ; // pas de dossier à enlever
        }
        document.getElementById("displayLarge").src = "large/"+fichierNom;
    }

    function reverse(s) { // pour inverser une chaîne de caractères
        var o = '';
        for (var i = s.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            o += s[i];
        return o;
    }
    
</script>
</body>

</html>
```